# How do I get the resultset of a ActiveRecord query for a table that does not have a model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to connect to the data in a remote MySQL table, iterate through it, and use ActiveRecord "create" methods so that all validations and callbacks are performed.  I have found documentation for having multiple database config settings, and assigning them individually per model, but that doesn't fit my needs because I don't want to create models or migrations for a one time import.

So I found this other method of querying a database outside of AR:

```
base = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "XXX",
  :username => "YYY",
  :password => "ZZZ",
  :database => "AAA"
)

results = base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE 1")
```

But it returns an object that looks fairly inscrutable:

```
#<Mysql2::Result:0x007fdf6e8bb9d8>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
base.connection.select("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel).  You can put all of the functionality you need in there and have access to things such as validations.